# How can I get details about a Silverlight code generation exception?

Tags: silverlight, code-generation, wcf-ria-services

I'm getting the following error now when I build my Silverlight Business Application:

The code generator

> 'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.CSharpCodeDomClientCodeGenerator'
>   encountered a fatal exception and
>   could not generate code for project
>
> 'C:\Software\ProjectPartCenterAdmin\Alpha\Latest 
>   Version\ProjectPartCenterAdmin\ProjectPartCenterAdmin.csproj':
>
> Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.

I DID ABSOLUTELY NOTHING TO MY CODE since it last worked! All I did was a clean rebuild of the application.  Is there a way to get the details on what the exception was?  I am dead in the water until i can figure this out.

Oh, and by the way, I hate code generation!  I've had endless problems with RIA Services and I'm trying my best to do things "the right way"; that is, no hacks.

**Edit:**

I've also been getting a similar warning:

> The following exception occurred
>   creating the MEF composition
>   container:
>
> Unable to load one or more
>   of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.
>
> The default code
>   generator will be used.

I've been getting this for some time now, and have ignored it because the application seems to be working fine.

Also, when I remove my `CustomValidation` attributes the exception goes away. But the warnings do not.

Comment: Same problem. Didn't touch my code and this started happening. Did you resolve?

Comment: If your building inside VS it tends to swallow a lot of build errors. Try building it on the command line

Comment: @Ronnie, No, this remains unresolved.  I worked around it by rebuilding my project from scratch, about an hour of work. :( I know that it has something to do with generated code (obviously), and I think its a RIA services thing because I don't think the DBML designer uses `CodeDom`.  Those two are the only extensive code generators that I'm using.

Comment: One thing you might try, it's resolved issues for me in the past. If you have mutiple projects in your solutiomn (like a typical Web project + Silverlight project) - set another project as the startup project, rebuild, then set it back to the previous project. Sounds strange, but this has worked for me.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try next time it happens.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if there were custom validation errors in the project. I had the same issue but when I realized that I had two validation result methods with the same name! and change it, the built was successfull.