# Can't find cause of code generation exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a silverlight/asp.net project. I cannot build because of this error:

> The code generator
>   'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.CSharpCodeDomClientCodeGenerator'
>   encountered a fatal exception and
>   could not generate code for project
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation

The only thing I've found on this are:

[How can I get details about a Silverlight code generation exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329052/how-can-i-get-details-about-a-silverlight-code-generation-exception)

[Exception thrown by the target of an invocation in Microsoft.RIA.Client.targets](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/662780/exception-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-in-microsoft-ria-client-targets)

Those resources aren't helping me, though. How can I determine the cause of this exception?